# Azure - Auto start website post deployment

Tags: c#, azure, web, web-deployment

I have a web site on Azure and post deployment, the site is down till the first hit to it. I want something that will auto start the site after deployment or when it resets. Is there any way?

Note - I am looking for an answer for Azure and not IIS on windows machine.

Comment: I presume you're hosting it on Azure Web Sites? If so, I believe this behavior isn't restricted to a new web site but also any site that sits idle for a given period of time. The common approach is to have a 'heartbeat' request from an external service (usually some type of monitor) that can keep the site warmed up.

Comment: I believe enabling the Always On option in your Azure Web Site config will do this as well.

Comment: Is there a way in Azure only (maybe by scripting) which will help make the page request for the first time?

Comment: @BenV - "Always On" option makes sure that the pool doesnt resets. But when deployment happens, the site would not be turned on till first page hit. That is the time when it warms up

Comment: From [Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/windows-azure-staging-publishing-support-for-web-sites-monitoring-improvements-hyper-v-recovery-manager-ga-and-pci-compliance): When Always On is enabled on a site, Windows Azure will automatically ping your Web Site regularly to ensure that the Web Site is always active and in a warm/running state.